# How to send back response with html file to ejs file and show in iframe on ejs Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, httpresponse

I'm newbie in Node.js and working on the server. I'm trying to send response back my output file(html) to ejs in NodeJS. I'll explain more details below,

I have a button that sends HTTP request('POST') to run python file in ejs like below code,

**In EJS,**

```
<div class="form-group" style='margin-bottom:0px;'><div id='Button'><input type='button' class="form-control" value='Request' id="sendButton" onclick="save3()"/></div></div>
<form action="/saveText" method="POST" id="myForm"><input type="hidden" id="metrics_id" ng-repeat="obj in tags" value="{{obj.name}}" name="metrics_name"></form>

<script>
  function save3(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByName("metrics_name")[0].value);
    console.log(document.getElementsByName("metrics_name")[1].value);
    console.log(myForm.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
  }
  $(document).on('click', '#sendButton', function(){
    $('#myForm').submit();
  });
</script>
```

And then it calls python script to execute in app.js(Node.js) using PythonShell

**Node.JS**

```
app.post('/saveText', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  var pyshell = new PythonShell('/public/make_bokeh.py');
  pyshell.on('message', function(message){
    console.log(message);
  });
  pyshell.end(function(err){
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    console.log("Finished");
    res.sendFile(); ------------------------>I want to send output file back to EJS
  });
});
```

From the make_bokeh.py, it creates output html file in same directory as where make_bokeh.py is.

The problem is I want to send HTTP response back to ejs with that output file, and then put it into iframe.

Is it going to be possible, or is there any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you can do:

## Node JS

```
. . .
pyshell.end(function(err){
if(err){
  throw err;
}
console.log("Finished");
var HTMLFileGeneratedByPython = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, relPath));
  res.render('template.ejs', { htmlFile: HTMLFileGeneratedByPython });
});
```

## EJS

```
<!-- HTML HEADER -->
<body>
  <%= htmlFile %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering my question. I'll try out and let you know :)

Comment: It gives me an error with `htmlFile is not defined` when It goes to ejs first before clicking button. Should I edit like  "<%= htmlFile %>" ?

Comment: Wait hm.. I think I got it.. I have to think for a second

Comment: I'm not sure of my code to get the HTML file. You need to have the HTML content in the ```HTMLFileGeneratedByPython ``` so you can print it in your ejs file :)

Comment: yeah I figured out Thanks a lot! :)